# C#: Listbox CrossThreading Issues

Tags: c#, synchronization

I am trying to access 3 listbox elements in my program from a different thread and keep getting the cross thread exceptions. I need a way to access my listboxes from another thread and have that code in a separate class called threadUtilities.cs. This way, all my thread access related code will be in a seperate class. Can anyone please provide generic code to access any listbox from another thread?

Answer (score 2):

You want to get the [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) from the UI thread and then make it available to the background threads.

Depending on what technology you are using, a derived `SynchronizationContext` will be made available, but that's not of concern really; the [`Current` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current.aspx) will return the one that is currently installed and both Windows Forms and WPF will install the proper one for you.

With the `SynchronizationContext` passed to the thread you want to make calls from, you can then call the [`Send` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.send.aspx) (analogous to the [`Invoke` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.invoke.aspx)) or the [`Post` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post.aspx) (analogous to the [`BeginInvoke` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.begininvoke.aspx)) depending on your needs.

Here's an example:

```
public void Button1_OnClick(sender object, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the current SynchronizationContext.
    // NOTE: Must make the call on the UI thread, NOT
    // the background thread to get the proper
    // context.
    SynchronizationContext context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    // Start some work on a new Task (4.0)
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { 
        // Do some lengthy operation.
        ...

        // Notify the user.  Do not need to wait.
        context.Post(o => MessageBox.Show("Progress"));

        // Do some more stuff.
        ...

        // Wait on result.
        // Notify the user.
        context.Send(o => MessageBox.Show("Progress, waiting on OK"));
    });
}
```

Also, it should be mentioned that the [`BackgroundWorker` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) does all of this for you behind the scenes; if this model works for you over using the `SynchronizationContext` directly, then by all means, use that (the `BackgroundWorker` class uses `SynchronizationContext` internally).

Comment: can you provide an example of how to do this? I am totally new at coding and this is my first experience with backgrounding. How exactly does one declare and use the SynchronizationContext. (ie pass to thread you want to make calls from etc.)

Comment: @Paul: Updated answer with example.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether it's WinForms or WPF. If WinForms, use the Control.Invoke method. If WPF, use the Dispatcher.

Simple WinForms sample:

```
ListBox listBox = GetListBoxFromSomewhere();
if( listBox.InvokeRequired )
    listBox.Invoke(() => listBox.Items.Add("Some item");
else
    listBox.Items.Add("Some item");
```

You could make a generic function for UI access like so:

```
void PerformUIOperation(Control c, Action action)
{
    if( c.InvokeRequired )
        c.Invoke(action);
    else
        action();
}
```

Use like this:

```
PerformUIOperation(listBox, () => listBox.Items.Add("Some item");
```

Comment: I added an example. Alternatively, use the BackgroundWorker to create your threads, and its ProgressChanged event to access the UI.

Comment: Yea im using background worker and i am in another class so i cant access listbox directly. I read on ways to use delagtes to do this type of operation but the examples only covered one listbox per delegate and they too were using the delagate in the form class so had access to the listbox element

Comment: If you are using BackgroundWorker you should use the ReportProgress method and do all your UI access from the ProgressChanged event (and RunWorkerCompleted event). These events are guaranteed to run on the UI thread.

Comment: @Sven: Have to -1; [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) is now the way to go.  It was meant to prevent the programmer from having to worry about *how* to marshal calls in any context (which is what you are promoting) and use one unified model

Comment: How do you use SynchronizationContext? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I tried Sven's exmaple and it works perfectly if i have the performuioperation method in the form class. IT fails if i have it in another class though. WHy is that?

Comment: `SynchronizationContext` is indeed a better option (or indeed `BackgroundWorker`, as I've been saying). I didn't think of using `SynchronizationContext` because I haven't done much UI work lately.

Comment: How do you use SynchronizationContext to do what i need?

Comment: @Sven & @Paul: Updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253384/c-listbox-crossthreading-issues/6253526#6253526) with an example of how to use `SynchronizationContext`.